# How to check user facebook likes/post in django

Tags: python, django, facebook

I need to check if my users liked or posted to pages. I've tried a few of the packages around (facebook_api, django-facebook) but cannot seem to login using my access_token, or get an fql request working.
This will be a cron job, not a page load. The user will not be logged in.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what pages? Fan page  or site page?

Comment: I'd like to check it from a cron job, using the fql api

Comment: Facebook had depreciated offline_access, there is no way to that

Comment: But that is public information - if I just go to the user's page I can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of Django Facebook, this is how you could do it:

Implement a registration flow, have a look at the docs.
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Now that your users can register the database will contain the access_token and facebook id for the users.
In your cronjob you can do things like:

```
from open_facebook.api import OpenFacebook
graph = OpenFacebook(access_token)
graph.get('%s/likes' % facebook_id)
graph.fql('SELECT ... FROM like WHERE post_id = A and user_id = B')
```

for a cronjob i would use
    graph.batch_fql(dictionary_with_queries) for better performance